# Appending to an object in a list of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript array that contains objects and looks like this:

```
[{‘sku':’ASD',’price': 10.99,’name':’Hot Sauce',’quantity': 1}, {‘sku':’JKL',’price': 8.99,’name':’Chilli Peppers',’quantity': 1}, {‘sku':’UIO',’price':’10.50',’name': "Sip 'n' Sizzle T-Shirt",’quantity': 1}]
```

I have a variable that contains the subtotal for the entire order and I would like to append it to each object for database purposes.

I tried this, but it messed everything up.:

```
var allProdData = prodData.push({total: total})
```

I assume I have to a use a for loop, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Comment: You're not sure how to use a for loop? Or how to add a new property to an object?

Comment: Little bit of both, coming from python.  JS is quite foreign to me.

Comment: You're saying that you want to add the subtotal to each individual object in the Array, right? Is it the same subtotal, or do you mean you want to calculate the subtotal per object from `quantity * price`?

Comment: Right.  It is the same subtotal

Comment: That's what I thought. I don't understand what the answers below are doing, but all you need is `for (var i = 0; i < prodData.length; i++) prodData[i].subtotal = the_subtotal;`

Comment: ...or `prodData.forEach(function(obj) { obj.subtotal = the_subtotal; });`

Comment: Great, I will try these out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First give a correct format for your array like below:

```
var arr = [{sku:'ASD',price: 10.99,name:'Hot Sauce',quantity: 1}, ...]
```

Then loop the array, calculate the total and format a new array

```
var arrNew = [];


for (var i  = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

    var total = arr[i].price * arr[i].quality;
    arrNew.push({sku:arr[i].sku,price: arr[i].price,name:arr[i].name,quantity: arr[i].quality, total:total});
}
```

Comment: Well, what what you say about var arrOther isn't quite true.  It is just an integer variable.  It is a dynamic sum of all items.  I will try and see if this works though.  Your comment says "here I assume that your another array should have the same length as your first array"  can i turn the var integer into an array?

Comment: Do you mean your total is just an `integer` or is an `integer array`?

Comment: It is just an integer.  This is how it is created `for (var x in prodData) total += prodData[x].price * prodData[x].quantity
    total = Math.round(total * 100) / 100`.  It is dynamically updated as more items are added to the list.

Comment: ok. Answer is updated. You can format a new array like what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago try this

```
for(key in Objectname){
    var allProdData = prodData.push(Objectname[key].total)
}
```

Put the correct objectname

Comment: What is the object in this situation? My objects are all in one array, I'm not sure that they have names.

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the question being asked.